# How to remove GRUB from Windows laptop (MS Surface Pro 3) - the 4x BootRec commands did not work

Tags: grub, windows-11, microsoft-surface-pro

I have Windows 11 running on my MS SP3 laptop. I had Ubuntu also installed, but removed the partitions for it. The laptops DOES still boot, but I have to type "exit" at the `GRUB` screen - how can I just get rid of the `GRUB` screen at boot up?

I have booted to a Win11 installer on a flash drive and ran the 4x `BootRec.exe` commands, but they did not fix this:

```
BootRec /FixMbr
# "The operation completed successfully"
BootRec /FixBoot
# Access is denied
BootRec /ScanOs
# Total identified Windows installations: 0
BootRec /RebuildBCD
# Total identified Windows installations: 0
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: What commands exactly did you run, provide this vital information, by editing your question

Comment: The command your running is only applicable to Windows 7

Comment: I see, thanks @Ramhound. Do you know what the equivalent command is in Windows 11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Where `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootsect /nt60` and the Ubuntu live with the `boot-repair` suggestions have failed, this has worked for me:

(This answer borrowed verbatim from [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/))

> 1. Run a `cmd.exe` process with administrator privileges
> 2. Run `diskpart`
> 3. Type: `list disk` then `sel disk X` where X is the drive your boot files reside on
> 4. Type `list vol` to see all partitions (volumes) on the disk (the EFI volume will be formatted in FAT, others will be NTFS)
> 5. Select the EFI volume by typing: `sel vol Y` where Y is the `SYSTEM` volume (this is almost always the EFI partition)
> 6. For convenience, assign a drive letter by typing: `assign letter=Z:` where Z is a free (unused) drive letter
> 7. Type `exit` to leave disk part
> 8. While still in the `cmd` prompt, type: `Z:` and hit enter, where Z was the drive letter you just created.
> 9. Type `dir` to list directories on this mounted EFI partition
> 10. If you are in the right place, you should see a directory called `EFI`
> 11. Type `cd EFI` and then `dir` to list the child directories inside `EFI`
> 12. Type `rmdir /S ubuntu` to delete the ubuntu boot directory

Assuming you only ever had two operating systems (Win 10 & Ubuntu) you should now be able to boot directly to Windows without hitting the black grub screen.